# How to run a loop by interlinking two lists?

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists, one for contract names of a website and another one for its links. I have 3rd list which includes some contract names which can be present in list 1. So I want to run a loop that will take contract names from the 3rd list and will find a hyperlink and open that hyperlink. I fit does not find any link then it will return a string(not found).

li1 contract names(10 to 15)
li2 contract links(number is same as list 1)
li3 random contract name.

Comment: To clarify things and to improve your question you should add the following to your post:  1) short examples of the three lists (input), 2) the result you want (output), and 3) some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana']
links = ['apple.gov', 'orange.net', 'pear.org', 'banana.com']
link_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(names, links)}

selected_names = ['apple', 'banana', 'poodle']

results = [link_dict[n] if n in names else 'not found' for n in selected_names]
```